# Adding Hyperlink with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a hyperlink to an excel cell like this but getting an error:

```
rng.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(cell.Offset(0, 3).Value,"">"")"
```

Basically the hyperlink is located within another cell and i want to have the text `">"` appear in the new hyperlink cell.

Comment: what is the relationship between **rng** and **cell** ??

Comment: none... rng is a range in the new sheet. cell is a range in the old sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Hyperlinks collection:

```
Sheet1.Hyperlinks.Add Sheet1.Range("A1"), "http://longLinkAddressHere", , , ">"
```

Comment: ok this actually works flawlessly ! sorry Gary for changing to this answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some double quotes:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1")
    Set cell = Range("A2")

    rng.Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & cell.Offset(0, 3).Value & ""","">""  )"

End Sub
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: My final formula is this but I am getting an error when I run it rng2.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" & cell.Offset(0, 3).Value & ""","">""  )"

Comment: are you sure this syntax works if the cells are not defined so simply ?

Comment: @JoannaMikalai  Try to **MsgBox** the string before you use it in the formula.

Comment: which string are you referring to?

Comment: ok when i messagebox the string it looks ok, but when i use it in my syntax as i said it gives an error

Comment: ok the problem is that my links are longer than 255 characters.. any solutions?

Comment: You must find a way to shorten the links............. **How would you enter the formula manually ??**

Comment: apparently, if the link is placed as plain text inside a cell it is fine. When i try to make it part of a formula, I get the max characters limit error